# Simplifying $\cot\alpha(1-\cos2\alpha)$. I get $\sin 2\alpha$; book says $-4\sin\alpha$.

Tags: trigonometry

Please help simplify expression

\begin{align}\cot\alpha\ (1-\cos2\alpha)\end{align}
I tried to solve through this way:
First dividing and multiplying both parts by $2$

\begin{align}\cot\alpha\ (1-\cos2\alpha)= 2\cot\alpha\sin^2\alpha\end{align}

Second reducing the degree and sin of cot
\begin{align}2\cos\alpha\sin\alpha=\sin 2\alpha\end{align}
But in book there is $-4\sin\alpha$

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your answer is correct, the book's wrong.

Comment: You can tell the book is wrong because $1-\cos 2\alpha$ is never negative and, for (say) $\alpha$ in the first quadrant, $\cot \alpha$ is positive. Therefore, the initial expression is non-negative for first-quadrant angles, so that any equivalent expression should be, too; however, $-4\sin\alpha$ is negative for such angles.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct. The answer $-4\sin\alpha$ in your book isn't correct. Substitute $\cot\alpha=\frac{\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}$ to get to correct answer $$2\cot\alpha\sin^2\alpha=2\frac{\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}\sin^2\alpha=2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha=\color{blue}{\sin2\alpha}$$